# javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, validation

Is it something wrong with this script?

```
function validation() {
  var message, x;
  message = document.getElementsByClassName("message");
  message.innerHTML = "";
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("inputNumber").value;

  try { 

      if(isNaN(x)) throw "Input is not a number";

  }
  catch(err) {
      message.innerHTML = err;
  }
```

}

The HTML is this:

```
    <input type="number" class="form-control inputNumber" onkeyup="validation()" >
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    <p class="message"></p>
```

The console doesn't show any errors but the validation doesn't happen.

Comment: The `.getElementsByClassName()` function returns a **list** of elements. You can't treat the return value as if it were a single element.

Comment: Here are some docs on [_NodeList_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and [_HTMLCollection_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: so should I use ".getElementById()" ? What if I have more inputs that requests numbers? I can't give the same ID.  Sorry, I am a beginner.

Comment: Forms have an [*elements*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#dom-form-elements) collection that is all the controls in the form. You can iterate over that for validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

> Just for testing purpose I have set `type='text'`. I have passed the current context of the input field as an argument so that I can relate other closest elements using that context.

```js
function validation(elem) {
  var message, x;
  message = elem.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
  message.innerHTML = "";
  x = elem.value;
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    message.innerHTML = "Input is not a number";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control inputNumber" onkeyup="validation(this)">

<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
<p class="message"></p>
```

Comment: thank you, it works. Can you explain why you used 'onkeyup="validation(this)" ' ? why "(this)" ?

Comment: @ValeriaMelinte, If you have only one text field then you can have `id` to that element and can manipulate your `DOM` using `document.getElementById(`yourId`)`

Comment: I have more, that's why I'm using classes

Comment: If you have multiple elements then you must have some identifier for your element. And this is the reason I am passing `this` as an argument to identify that element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89071/discussion-between-valeria-melinte-and-rayon-dabre).

Answer (score 0):

The `.getElementsByClassName()` function returns a list of elements. So you have to treat them as array
Change your code with this

```
message = document.getElementsByClassName("message");
message[0].innerHTML = "";
 x = document.getElementsByClassName("inputNumber")[0].value;
```

Comment: This could still be error prone if he has other elements that share that class name.

Comment: What if there are multiple input boxes with multiple error message containers ?

Comment: yes but by given code we can solve this by using it .